# Jasper server Report Service

Tags: java, rest, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have JSESSIONID that i get from *JasperReports Server* RestAPI POST call. How can i use this sessionID for the future Report Service API calls? I am using REST API. Can any one give me a sample or any source code or any solution for this. I dont want to create LDAP/CAS for singllr-signon business. Please help me to trouble shoot this in Java.

Steps that i followed:
1. created session using *JasperReports Server* POST rest api call
2. tried to use that sessionID in the future /report service.

Answer (score 1):

Add new header "cookie", and set value = JSESSIONID, send your further request with the header.